# Firebase no encuentra la foto que intento subir desdemi App

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy intentando subir una imagen a Firebase Cloud Storage pero cuando presiono el botón "Subir Imagen"la aplicación se detiene. Cabe mencionar que tengo otra activity con el mismo código y funciona con normalidad. Sin embargo, al replicarlo en otra activity no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He revisado el Logcat y visualizo el siguiente mensaje:

```
2020-06-03 15:23:29.304 23377-23450/com.example.barbercut E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2020-06-03 15:23:29.307 23377-23450/com.example.barbercut E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
2020-06-03 15:23:29.387 616-797/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [] mConsumerName == NULL!!!!!!
```

public class fotodni extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int RC_GALERY = 123;
private static final int RC_CAMERA = 124;

private static final int RP_CAMERA = 125;
private static final int RP_STORAGE = 126;

private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/MyPhotoApp";
private static final String MY_DNI = "my_dni";

private static final String PATH_DOCUMENTOS = "documentos";
private static final String PATH_DNI = "DNI";
private static final String PHOTO_DNI = "Foto_Dni";
@BindView(R.id.container)
ConstraintLayout container;
@BindView(R.id.progressBar)
ProgressBar progressBar;

private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private Uri mPhotoSelectedUri;

private Button pasaPenales;
private ImageView photoProfile;
private Button upPhoto, selectPhoto, capturePhoto;
private ImageButton closePhoto;
private TextView mTvMessage;

private StorageReference mStorageReference;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
private DatabaseReference mDataBase2;

private BarberProvider mBarberProvider;
private AuthProviders mAuthProvider;

private TextView nameProfile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_fotodni);

    nameProfile=findViewById (R.id.dniProfile);

    mBarberProvider = new BarberProvider ();
    mAuthProvider =new AuthProviders ();

    mFirebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();
    mDataBase2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ();


    myToolbar.show (this, "Foto DNI", true);

    pasaPenales = findViewById (R.id.btnDNI2);
    pasaPenales.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToSelectAuth5 ();
        }
    });

    photoProfile = findViewById (R.id.photoDNI1);
    upPhoto = findViewById (R.id.upPhotoProfile);
    selectPhoto = findViewById (R.id.select_Photo);
    capturePhoto = findViewById (R.id.capture_Photo);
    closePhoto = findViewById (R.id.btnDelete);
    mTvMessage = findViewById (R.id.messageLoad);

    getClientInfo();

    upPhoto.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadPhoto ();
        }
    });


    selectPhoto.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkPermissionToApp (Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RP_STORAGE);
            //fromGallery ();
        }
    });

    capturePhoto.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //captureCamara ();
            //dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            checkPermissionToApp (Manifest.permission.CAMERA, RP_CAMERA);
        }
    });

    closePhoto.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeImage ();
        }
    });

    configFirebase ();
    configPhotoProfile ();
```

}

```
private void configPhotoProfile() {
    mStorageReference.child (PATH_DOCUMENTOS).child (MY_DNI).getDownloadUrl ()
            .addOnSuccessListener (new OnSuccessListener<Uri> () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    final RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions ()
                            .centerCrop ()
                            .diskCacheStrategy (DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE);

                    Glide.with (fotodni.this)
                            .load (uri)
                            .apply (options)
                            .into (photoProfile);

                    closePhoto.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener (new OnFailureListener () {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    closePhoto.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText (fotodni.this, "Agregar Otra Imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
            });
}

private void configFirebase() {
    mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance ().getReference ();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
    mDatabaseReference = database.getReference ().child (PATH_DOCUMENTOS).child (PATH_DNI);
}

private void checkPermissionToApp(String permissionStr, int requestPermission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission (this, permissionStr) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (this, new String[]{permissionStr}, requestPermission);
            return;
        }
    }

    switch (requestPermission) {
        case RP_STORAGE:
            fromGallery ();
            break;
        case RP_CAMERA:
            dispatchTakePictureIntent ();
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RP_STORAGE:
                fromGallery ();
                break;
            case RP_CAMERA:
                dispatchTakePictureIntent ();
                break;
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

private void captureCamara() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult (intent, RC_CAMERA);
}

private void fromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult (intent, RC_GALERY);

}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity (getPackageManager ()) != null) {
        File photoFile;
        photoFile = createImageFile ();

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile (this,
                    "com.example.barbercut", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult (takePictureIntent, RC_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() {
    final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy_HHmmss", Locale.ROOT)
            .format (new Date ());
    final String imageFileName = MY_DNI + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = null;
    try {
        image = File.createTempFile (imageFileName, "jpg", storageDir);
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath ();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    return image;
}


private void closeImage() {
    mStorageReference.child (PATH_DOCUMENTOS).child (MY_DNI).delete ().addOnSuccessListener (new OnSuccessListener<Void> () {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            mDatabaseReference.removeValue ();
            photoProfile.setImageBitmap (null);
            closePhoto.setVisibility (View.GONE);
            Snackbar.make (container, R.string.main_message_delete_succes, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener (new OnFailureListener () {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Snackbar.make (container, R.string.main_message_delete_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_GALERY:
                if (data != null) {
                    mPhotoSelectedUri = data.getData ();

                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap (this.getContentResolver ()
                                , mPhotoSelectedUri);
                        photoProfile.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
                        closePhoto.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                        mTvMessage.setText (R.string.main_message_question_upload);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RC_CAMERA:
                /*Bundle extras = data.getExtras ();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get ("data");*/
                mPhotoSelectedUri = addPicGallery ();

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap (this.getContentResolver ()
                            , mPhotoSelectedUri);
                    photoProfile.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
                    closePhoto.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                    mTvMessage.setText (R.string.main_message_question_upload);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}

private Uri addPicGallery() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File file = new File (mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile (file);
    mediaScanIntent.setData (contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast (mediaScanIntent);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    return contentUri;
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}



private void loadPhoto() {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Bitmap bitmap;

    try{
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver() , mPhotoSelectedUri);
        bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 480);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        StorageReference profileReference = mStorageReference.child(PATH_DOCUMENTOS);
        StorageReference photoReference = profileReference.child (PHOTO_DNI).child(mAuthProvider.getId () + ".jpg");
        UploadTask uploadTask = photoReference.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) /
                                taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        progressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
                        mTvMessage.setText(String.format("%s%%", progress));
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Snackbar.make(container, R.string.main_message_upload_success, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String image = uri.toString ();
                                Barber barber = new Barber ();
                                barber.setImage (image);
                                savePhotoUrl2 (uri);

                                closePhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mTvMessage.setText(R.string.main_message_done);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(container, R.string.main_message_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (true){
        return;
    }
    StorageReference profileReference = mStorageReference.child (PATH_DOCUMENTOS);
    StorageReference photoReference = profileReference.child (MY_DNI);

    photoReference.putFile (mPhotoSelectedUri)
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) /
                            taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
                    mTvMessage.setText(String.format("%s%%", progress));
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            })

            .addOnSuccessListener (new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Snackbar.make (container, R.string.main_message_upload_succes, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                    taskSnapshot.getStorage ().getDownloadUrl ().addOnSuccessListener (new OnSuccessListener<Uri> () {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            savePhotoUrl2 (uri);
                            Barber barber = new Barber ();
                            String image = uri.toString ();
                            barber.setImage (image);
                            closePhoto.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                            mTvMessage.setText (R.string.main_message_done);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener (new OnFailureListener () {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Snackbar.make (container, R.string.main_message_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        }
    });
}

private void savePhotoUrl2(Uri downloadUri) {
    mDatabaseReference.setValue (downloadUri.toString ());
}

private void goToSelectAuth5() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (fotodni.this, fotoDNI2.class);
    startActivity (intent);
}

private void getClientInfo(){
    mBarberProvider.getBarber (mAuthProvider.getId ()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener () {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists ()){
                String name = dataSnapshot.child ("dni").getValue ().toString ();
                nameProfile.setText (name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Suponiendo que la ruta de la imagen es correcta, el valor de mAuthProvider.getId() obtiene un nombre de imagen valido?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Efectivamente, el valor mAuthProvider.getId() sí obtiene el id del cliente. Lo comprobé haciendo una prueba con otro dato.

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando de obtener un objeto el cual no existe:

> "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Not Found. Could not get object",
>   "status": "GET_OBJECT" }} java.io.IOException: { "error": { "code":
>   404, "message": "Not Found. Could not get object", "status":
>   "GET_OBJECT" }}

**el problema se debe a que tratas de obtener una referencia no existente**, en este caso debes definir

```
  private static final String PATH_DOCUMENTOS = "documentos";
  private static final String PATH_DNI = "DNI";
  ...
  ...
  StorageReference profileReference = mStorageReference.child(PATH_DOCUMENTOS);
  StorageReference photoReference = profileReference.child (PHOTO_DNI).child(mAuthProvider.getId () + ".jpg");
```

Debes revisar si la imagen se encuentra en realidad dentro de `documentos/DNI/` y que  `mAuthProvider.getId()` obtenga un nombre de imagen existente.

Comment: Lo revisé y tengo el mismo resultado. Se detiene al intentar subir la imagen al storage.